# MFMessageComposer: Knowing How Many Recipients The Message Was Sent Too?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Is there a way to know the amount of recipients the users sent a message too? The only thing I see is

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
```

But unfortunately it isn't helpful. My intention is to reward users with 1 coin for every recipient that they invite (Max 10 possible). Help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The API is intentionally vague so that you cannot see any information. This is to protect the user's privacy. Likewise with `MFMailComposeViewController`.

If you need to provide a functionality that cannot be achieved using `MFMessageComposeViewController`, you will have to roll your own solution. This can be difficult to achieve as you would need a messaging service, and you will not be able to send messages from the users accounts. Better redesign your reward system.